# C++ std::list paramerter with default values

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, parameters, default-value, stdlist

I want to have a method that takes a list as a parameter but this list should have default values, here is an invalid example for what I need:

```
void myFunc(std::list<CString> const & myList = std::list<CString>({"Val1", "Val2", "Val3"}));
```

When I try to use it I get

> Error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before '{'

Comment: you could check if it is empty and initialize it to that..

Comment: And how do you know that attempt is invalid? What errors do you get?

Comment: what is wrong with it? I dont know what `CString` is, but otherwise your approach [seems to be fine](http://ideone.com/oT4uR4)

Comment: you can't really have a default value for a reference, because the reference necessarily references something else, in this case the default would be that nothing else existed

Comment: [This works](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/464d2c737d410739).  What error do you get?

Comment: @tobi303 that may be legal (I don't actually know), but I don't understand the utility of it.

Comment: this is the error: error C2143: Syntaxfehler: Es fehlt ')' vor '{'

Comment: your compiler speaks german and c++? I took both in highschool, but am not really great at either.

Comment: @muaz What compiler and version are you using?

Comment: the utility of it being a reference in that case.

Comment: please show a [mcve]. I didnt manage to reproduce the error you report with the line you show here

Comment: @GradyPlayer ..that no copy has to be made when a parameter is passed

Comment: @NathanOliver it is Visual Studio 2010 compiler

Comment: @muaz This code will not work in MSVS 2010.  It does not support C++11.  You will need to upgrade your compiler.  If you can get 2017 as it is the most complaint compiler they have.

Comment: @NathanOliver but still there should be a way to address this for my current compiler

Comment: @muaz Take a look at [this list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/hh567368.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Micrsoft Visual Studio 2010 [does not support `std::initializer_list`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx).  When you do

```
std::list<CString>({"Val1", "Val2", "Val3"})
```

You attempt to initialize the `std::list` using it's `std::initializer_list` constructor.  Since MSVS 2010 doesn't support that you can call it.

One thing you can do is write a function that creates and initializes a list like

```
std::list<CString> default_list()
{
    std::list<CString> temp;
    temp.push_back("Val1");
    temp.push_back("Val2");
    temp.push_back("Val3");
    return temp;
}
```

And then you can use that like

```
void myFunc(std::list<CString> const & myList = default_list());
```